# Solve the linear equations system AX = B in Python, np.linalg.solve not working

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, linear-equation

I'm trying to solve the linear equation AX=B where A,X,B are Matrices.
I've tried using the **np.linalg.solve** function of **numpy** but the result seems to be wrong.
Example:

```
Matrix A  
[9 1 8]  
[3 2 5]  
[1 6 5]  

Matrix B  
[7 0 5]  
[7 8 4]  
[5 6 7]
```

So to solve X, i've used:

```py
X = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

The result is:

```
X  
[ 1.17521368 -0.17948718  0.40598291]  
[ 0.20512821 -0.30769231  0.74358974]  
[-0.56410256 -0.15384615  1.20512821]
```

But if i try to verify the result by multiplying A by X, the result is anything but B:

```
B
[ 5.40598291 -2.02564103  8.86752137]  
[ 7.61111111 -4.33333333 13.61111111]  
[ 3.15811966 -3.82051282 14.92735043]
```

If i use this:

```
np.matmul(B, np.linalg.inv(A))
```

Instead of the solve function, i get the same results.

Is there something i am missing here?

**EDIT 1:** 
I've printed

```
np.allclose(np.dot(A, X), B)
```

And is returning **False**

**EDIT 2**
Here is the code i'm using:

```py
B = np.array([7,0,5,7,8,4,5,6,7]).reshape(3,3)
A = np.array([9,1,8,3,2,5,1,6,5]).reshape(3,3)
X = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
print(x)
#[[-1.70967742 -4.48387097  0.08064516]
# [-1.35483871 -2.74193548  0.79032258]
# [ 2.96774194  5.38709677  0.43548387]]
```

My apologies if this is a very basic question, i appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the `A` and `B` you show produce that `X`.  What are `K` and `K1`?

Comment: My apologies, i've edited it to be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

My results with your arrays look right:

```
In [582]: A=np.array([9,1,8,3,2,5,1,6,5]).reshape(3,3)                                                
In [583]: B=np.array([7,0,5,7,8,4,5,6,7]).reshape(3,3)                                                
In [584]: x=np.linalg.solve(A,B)                                                                      
In [585]: x                                                                                           
Out[585]: 
array([[-1.70967742, -4.48387097,  0.08064516],
       [-1.35483871, -2.74193548,  0.79032258],
       [ 2.96774194,  5.38709677,  0.43548387]])
In [586]: A@x                                                                                         
Out[586]: 
array([[7., 0., 5.],
       [7., 8., 4.],
       [5., 6., 7.]])
```

The other approach: `AX=B` => `X=1/A B`:

```
In [591]: np.linalg.inv(A)@B                                                                          
Out[591]: 
array([[-1.70967742, -4.48387097,  0.08064516],
       [-1.35483871, -2.74193548,  0.79032258],
       [ 2.96774194,  5.38709677,  0.43548387]])
```

And formally testing for equality:

```
In [602]: np.allclose(A@np.linalg.solve(A, B), B)                                                       
Out[602]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `X` is correct. To verify if your solution is correct, as per the [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) you can use [`allclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) which should return `True` if two arrays (`AX` and `B`)are equal element-wise, within a tolerance.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[9, 1, 8], [3, 2, 5], [1, 6, 5]])  
B = np.array([[7, 0, 5], [7, 8, 4], [5, 6, 7]])  

X = np.linalg.solve(A,B)

np.allclose(np.dot(A, X), B)
# True
```

In your case, it indeed returns `True`.

Comment: np.allclose(np.dot(A,X),B) is returning false.

Comment: @JoséCousiño: For me it returns `True`. python 3.6.5 and numpy 1.14.3

Comment: I have Python 3.7.2 and numpy 1.16.0 and it is returning false