# NumPy ― Solve b = x * A

Tags: python, numpy

How can I solve the general equation b = x * A in NumPy? I can use the function numpy.linalg.lstsq given here (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to solve the equation b = A * x, but not the other way around.

Is there a method to solve this without matrix inversion?

I found a similar question here: [Solve the linear equations system AX = B in Python, np.linalg.solve not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333472/solve-the-linear-equations-system-ax-b-in-python-np-linalg-solve-not-working)

```
import numpy as np
...
z = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b) # Solves a@z = b.
```

Comment: take the transpose?  b^T = A^T x^T

Comment: @anon01 This should solve it, thanks.